# How do I ensure UTF-8 input encoding?

Tags: input-encodings

According to the babel manual, after 2018, I do not need to explicitly load the `inputenc` package --- ``if the encoding is UTF-8''.  So, how do I know which encoding my keyboard actually writes in?  And how do I change that to UTF-8?  Is it as simple as setting the encoding of my editor to UTF-8?  Do I have to change the region settings in my operating system?  Or do I have to change the settings in my keyboard?

If it makes a difference, my keyboard is set to English-International (so I can easily add accented characters).

Comment: It would be a setting in your editor. You can still add the line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your documents for PDTeX. LuaTeX and XeTeX already assume the input is in UTF-8. If you wanted to use a different encoding, you should probably load `selinput` so that your document compiles even if re-encoded.

Comment: If you say which editor you are using then someone will point you to where the setting is. Note however if `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is working then you are writing in utf-8 already, that does not change the file encoding just declares the encoding being used, so if that was wrong you would see weird low level errors.

Comment: You can also just try it out: compile your document, if the text in the pdf looks good, then the settings are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not your keyboard sending either utf-8 or whatever. The characters in a file are »encoded«, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding .

Any input by your keyboard is, regarding text files, controlled by a text editor, e.g. Emacs, vim, ...

The editor cares about the encoding, e.g. for Emacs see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChangingEncodings :

> When Emacs reads a file, it determines the encoding, reads the file, decodes it into an internal representation, and stores the coding-system used in a variable to be used when saving the file. When saving, the buffer is encoded using the stored coding-system and written to the file again.

The encoding of the filename is something completeley different, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename

For new files, you may change settings in your editor, either on a per file basis or for all files.

But if you change the settings, that doesn't change old files! So bear in mind that using an old file (or an old template) can still require to the package inputenc or selinput or you need to recode your file, which is a different kind of drama.

I haven't checked how the fontenc package deals with non utf-8 files.